# Symfony - Cache (Memcache) in a controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How do you using caching directly in a controller without queries (orm cache drivers)?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers

The documents only mention caching with doctrine but there are times it's needed without doctrine.  They don't appear to mention anything on this or is it one of the view things Symfony doesn't have a wrapper for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and use [DoctrineCacheBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineCacheBundle):

1. Add this bundle to your project as a composer dependency:

   ```
   composer require doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle
   ```
2. Add this bundle in your application kernel:

   ```
   // app/AppKernel.php
   public function registerBundles()
   {
       // ...
       $bundles[] = new \Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle();

       return $bundles;
   }
   ```
3. Configure it:

   ```
   # app/config/config.yml
   doctrine_cache:
       providers:
           my_apc_metadata_cache:
               type: apc
               namespace: metadata_cache_ns
           my_apc_query_cache:
               namespace: query_cache_ns
               apc: ~
           memcache:
               servers:
                   memcache01: 11211
   ```
4. Use it:

   ```
   $apcCache = $this->container->get('doctrine_cache.providers.my_apc_cache');
   $memcacheCache = $this->container->get('doctrine_cache.providers.memcache');
   ```

Read more: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineCacheBundle/usage.html 
Full providers reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineCacheBundle/reference.html

Comment: For completeness can you add how to configure memcache to be used with it since apc doesn't have any config options.

Comment: added memcache provider example

Comment: Just a quick comment to say that starting from 3.1, Symfony includes its own Cache component. So it won't be necessary to install the DoctrineCacheBundle.

Comment: @JavierEguiluz - can you share with us link to blog post or pull request?

Comment: @PawełMikołajczuk there is no official blog post yet, but you can see all the PRs related to this new component: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aclosed+label%3ACache  The integration is not fully completed yet. They are still fixing bugs and improving the integration with Symfony.